# Understanding scaling coefficients in the Naive Elastic Net

Tags: regression, lasso, regularization, ridge-regression, elastic-net

So I was reading [the original Elastic Net paper](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/B67.2%20(2005)%20301-320%20Zou%20&%20Hastie.pdf) by Zou, Hastie and I got slightly confused in the second section, where the reduction from Elastic Net to Lasso is performed.

They propose that an equivalent formulation of minimizing

$$||Y - X\beta||^2 + \lambda_2 ||\beta||^2_2 + \lambda_1 ||\beta||_1$$

is obtained after choosing an augmented dataset $(Y^*,X^*)$ of the form

$$X^* = (1+\lambda_2)^{-\frac12} \begin{pmatrix}X \\\sqrt{\lambda_2}I \end{pmatrix} , Y^* = \begin{pmatrix}Y \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
and they also rescale $\gamma = \frac{\lambda_1}{\sqrt{1+\lambda_2}}, \beta^* = \sqrt{1+\lambda_2}\beta$. Then they obtain the formulation

$$||Y^* - X^*\beta^*||^2 + \gamma ||\beta^*||.$$

I see that minimizing the new formulation is equivalent to the old one, given that one rescales the solution by the factor $(1+\lambda_2)^{-\frac12}$. However, this factor seems a bit arbitrary to me. Why has this factor been introduced, if one can also get a reduction to Lasso without it?